# Can a field be used for both input and output (example: exchange rate calculator)

Tags: front-end, dynamic, output, inputfield

Suppose I want to build a simple currency converter like this one:

[image]

The functionality is straightforward: enter an amount in any field box, it gets converted into other currencies whose fields are then output boxes.

The problem is to use the same fields for input and output, the input field being the one you choose to enter data. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Take a look at the second argument of `Dynamic`. You should be able to get something working with that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like Mike said in a comment, the key is to use the second argument of `Dynamic`. In this case I've built a function `updateCurrencies` which modifies a global variable `currencies` which holds an `Association` object with all the currency values in it.

```
currencies = <|
   "USDollars" -> 0,
   "Euros" -> 0,
   "BritishPounds" -> 0,
   "SwedishKronor" -> 0
   |>;

updateCurrencies[base_][value_, _] := currencies = AssociationMap[
   QuantityMagnitude@CurrencyConvert[Quantity[value, base], #] &, 
   Keys[currencies]
   ]

flag[country_] := Show[CountryData[country, "Flag"], ImageSize -> 40]

Grid[{
  {flag["USA"], InputField[Dynamic[currencies["USDollars"], updateCurrencies["USDollars"]], Number]},
  {flag["Britain"], InputField[Dynamic[currencies["BritishPounds"], updateCurrencies["BritishPounds"]], Number]},
  {flag["Sweden"], InputField[Dynamic[currencies["SwedishKronor"], updateCurrencies["SwedishKronor"]], Number]}
}, {Dividers -> All, Spacings -> 1.5 {1, 1}}]
```

[image: currency converter demo]

Comment: My version complains about `|<...>|`, are you using version 10?

Comment: @A.G. Yes, `Association` is new in version 10. But note that `Association` is only used because of its suitable syntax. This can be implemented without `Association` in Mathematica 9, using the second argument of `Dynamic` as is done here.